# Basics in for loop in actionscript 3 in flex

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

Good Morning stackoverflow...
I'm having a problem.... this is my sample code

```
var i:Number = new Number();

trace("showarray length" + showArray.length);

for(i=0;i<showArray.length;i++){

    trace("equal daw" + showArray.getItemAt(i).id + "==" + num);

    if(showArray.getItemAt(i).id == num){
        showArray.removeItemAt(i);

    }
}
trace('alerts');
```

myproblem here is...wherenever the if is satisfied it stops looping it immediately goes out of the loop

this is a sample output
given that the length of showArray is 2 and num = 0

showarray length2

equal daw0==0

alerts

please help me

Answer (score 8):

If you want to remove items while iterating over array, iterate in reverse order. This way element removal does not affect cycle condition:

```
for (var i:int = showArray.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (someCondition) {
        showArray.removeItemAt(i);
    }
}
```

Another small bonus that this is slightly faster, as it doesn't call showArray.length on each step.

Comment: Agree, have to iterate in reverse: answered very similar here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4946007/xml-nodes-will-not-delete-despite-calling-delete/4948647#4948647

Answer (score 3):

An even better way might be to use the `filter` method of the `Array` class.

```
array = array.filter(function (e:*, i:int, a:Array):Boolean {
        return e.id != num;
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

When your `if` is satisfied for `id == num` (which is 0 so happening in the first loop) and the item is removed, your array length decreases to 1 so the loop won't run any more.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you are removing items at the time you are iterating throught them.

```
array = [1, 2]
         ^         // pointer in first iteration

eliminate 1
array = [2]
         ^         // the pointer remains in the same location

//ups! out of the loop. all items were visited.
```

You can copy the array before you iterate through it and iterate the copy or mark the indices to remove and remove them later or iterate the array backwards.

PS: Sorry for my poor English.

Comment: Copying the array is unnecessary and slow, when you can just iterate through it backwards and have no problem

Answer (score 1):

After `showArray.removeItemAt(i);`, add `i--;`

Because you removed the item at index `i` from the array, the item that was at `i + 1` got moved to `i`. By subtracting one, you ensure that the moved item doesn't get skipped.

alxx's answer is also a good solution.